# Installing Apache Pig , why i see Hbase and Hive installing?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I was installing Apache pig's piggybank from [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank) tutorial.
While i was building source with **ant** , i observed its installing apache hive and hbase.
Can anyone tell me why its doing so?
Dose pig use **hive** and **hbase**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pig has HBase and Hive as dependencies because it has a [HBase loader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/package-summary.html) and a [Hive loader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/hiverc/package-summary.html) that come with the standard distribution.

I wouldn't worry about them getting installed. They are just building the jars, not deploying anything.

Comment: Ok , I read somewhere that its installed because it will be easier to configure pig with hbase or hive.But I didnt want hbase/hive so i made some changes in build file.But thanks.